# Python getting ips and macs from network

Tags: python, ip, scapy

I'm trying to get all IP's and their associated MAC address from the network.

Till now, i have the following code:

```
eth = Ether(dst = "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
arp = ARP(pdst = '198.13.13.1')
answered = srp1(eth / arp)
print answered[1].hwsrc
print answered[1].psrc
```

But this only gets me the MAC of what Ip i input.

I think i have to use:

```
answered, unanswered = srp(eth/arp)
```

And modify pdst with the address of the subnet but i don't know how to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you take a look `scanip`? https://pypi.org/project/scanip/1.0/

Comment: im requested to use srp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to enter your network as `pdst` field. You want to use a `timeout` because some probes probably won't get an answer. For example:

```
ans, unans = srp(Ether(dst=ETHER_BROADCAST) / ARP(pdst="198.13.13.0/24"), timeout=1)
```

Then you need to parse `ans`. If you want to get the MAC & IP addresses associated, you can create a list of tuples. For example:

```
res = [(pr.psrc, pr.hwsrc) for _, pr in ans]
print res
```

You can also use `arping()`, a specialized function for that purpose:

```
ans, unans = arping("198.13.13.0/24")
ans.show()
```